# why is gmcs command in bash(mono) missing the namespace `System.Threading'?

Tags: mono, gmcs

I input this command

```
gmcs -t:library Program.cs
```

and get this error

```
Program.cs(6,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Tasks' does not exist in the namespace `System.Threading'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

I get I have to give it the paths and everything, but how? can't find the way to do it

Comment: `gmcs` is not part of bash, and would behave the same way if you called it from any other shell, or with no shell at all. Thus, this question should not be tagged `bash`.

Comment: ...however, as `gmc` **is** part of `mono`, this question should be tagged `mono`.

Comment: Do you know that `System.Threading.Tasks` is actually installed? A bit of quick googling makes it look like some packagers may have moved it to an external library.

Comment: Similarly -- which version of Mono are you actually running?

Comment: hmmm... I'm running on a limited system... is it possible this dll is not included and I will have to add it?

Comment: Yes, very much possible. (See also `System.Threading.Tasks.Unofficial`).

Comment: ...with respect to the `reusable` error, btw, that looks more like a code bug than a command-line usage error. Without seeing your code, I don't know how anyone could help with it.

Comment: thx!! and about reusable, it's another namespace I use in the class... how can it not know where it is?

Comment: Again, we'd have to see the code, or -- better -- just enough code to reproduce the problem; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: it's just other *.cs I used, but for those I set a different namespace... but doesn't cause problem in the code, works well when not using the mono command line...

Comment: If you want to know how to reference other code in your project when building with mcs, why don't you ask a question **specifically** about that? Or better, look for whether someone else has already done so?

Comment: thx, this is what I'm doing right now. for now I have to leave but tomorrow morning I'll post it.
thx again

Comment: To be clear, by the way -- when you have no answers yet, it's better form to edit a question than to re-ask it (spamming with multiple copies of the same question is a route to a temporary ban). As currently written, this one is asking about a pair of errors, one of which is unrelated to split compilation, and its body text says nothing about compilation with dependencies between namespaces defined in multiple files.

Comment: What I'd suggest at this point is either editing this question to be on-point and removing the unrelated part, or editing it to only ask about `System.Threading.Tasks` and asking the other part separately.

Comment: did it to make it the most clear possible. Feel free to change it if there is still something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gmcs targets the .NET 2.0 profile, Task didn't exist back then.

On a recent Mono just use mcs, as [gmcs is deprecated](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/csharp/) and was removed from Mono 4.0.